# how to join a string with multiple values with a single one with xpath?

Tags: html, string, web-scraping, xpath

I have the following piece of html I'm trying to scrape from Beatport (electronic music store):

```
<div class="horz-release-meta-parent">
          <div class="horz-release-meta">
            
            <p class="buk-horz-release-title playlist-add-track"><a href="/release/the-flag-remix-2022/3927104">The Flag (Remix 2022)</a></p>
            <p class="buk-horz-release-artists">
        
            
    <a href="/artist/haldolium/10646" data-artist="10646">Haldolium</a>
        
    </p>
            <p class="buk-horz-release-labels">
    <a href="/label/blue-tunes-records/5188" data-label="5188">Blue Tunes Records</a></p>
            <p class="buk-horz-release-released">2022-12-07</p>
          </div>
          <div class="horz-release-actions-parent">
            <div class="horz-release-actions">
              <div class="horz-release-play-queue playlist-add-track">
                
                    <button class="playable-play" data-type="release" data-id="3927104" data-track="17096831">
                      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="play-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="/static/4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg#icon-play"></use>
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button class="playable-queue tooltip-secondary" data-type="release" data-id="3927104" data-track="17096831">
                      <svg viewBox="0 0 16 11" class="queue-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="/static/4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg#icon-add-queue"></use>
                      </svg>
                      <span class="tooltiptext">Add to queue</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="playable-playlist-add button-playlist-add button-icon space-right tooltip-secondary" data-modifier="release" data-type="release" data-id="3927104" data-track="17096831">
                      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="playlist-add-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="/static/4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg#icon-plus"></use>
                      </svg>
                      <span class="tooltiptext">Add to playlist</span>
                    </button>
                  
              </div>
              
              <div class="buy-button horz-release-buy-button" data-release="3927104" data-price="$1.29">
                
  
    <button class="add-to-default">$1.29</button>
    <button class="launch-menu">
    <div class="launch-menu-icon">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="/static/4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg#icon-chevron-down"></use>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="loading-menu-icon">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
    </button>
  

              </div>
              
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="icon icon-ellipsis horz-release-ellipsis mobile-action"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="horz-release-meta-parent">
          <div class="horz-release-meta">
            
            <p class="buk-horz-release-title playlist-add-track"><a href="/release/baileys/3931782">Baileys</a></p>
            <p class="buk-horz-release-artists">
        
            
    <a href="/artist/raz/105353" data-artist="105353">Raz</a>, 
        
    
        
            
    <a href="/artist/upgrade/252764" data-artist="252764">Upgrade</a>
        
    </p>
            <p class="buk-horz-release-labels">
    <a href="/label/regroup-records/33268" data-label="33268">Regroup Records</a></p>
            <p class="buk-horz-release-released">2022-12-07</p>
          </div>
          <div class="horz-release-actions-parent">
            <div class="horz-release-actions">
              <div class="horz-release-play-queue playlist-add-track">
                
                    <button class="playable-play" data-type="release" data-id="3931782" data-track="17110875">
                      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="play-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="/static/4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg#icon-play"></use>
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button class="playable-queue tooltip-secondary" data-type="release" data-id="3931782" data-track="17110875">
                      <svg viewBox="0 0 16 11" class="queue-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="/static/4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg#icon-add-queue"></use>
                      </svg>
                      <span class="tooltiptext">Add to queue</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="playable-playlist-add button-playlist-add button-icon space-right tooltip-secondary" data-modifier="release" data-type="release" data-id="3931782" data-track="17110875">
                      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="playlist-add-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="/static/4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg#icon-plus"></use>
                      </svg>
                      <span class="tooltiptext">Add to playlist</span>
                    </button>
                  
              </div>
              
              <div class="buy-button horz-release-buy-button" data-release="3931782" data-price="$1.29">
                
  
    <button class="add-to-default">$1.29</button>
    <button class="launch-menu">
    <div class="launch-menu-icon">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="/static/4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg#icon-chevron-down"></use>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="loading-menu-icon">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
    </button>
  

              </div>
              
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="icon icon-ellipsis horz-release-ellipsis mobile-action"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want to get the Artist and the Titles in the following format:

`ARTIST(S) - TITLE`

I have tried using **string-join** with this xpath:`//p[@class='buk-horz-release-artists']/string-join(a,",")` giving me this output:

```
Haldolium
Alter Vu
Raz,Upgrade
```

However, I want to join this xpath:

`//p[contains(@class,'buk-horz-release-title')]/a` which returns the album titles, but I can't seem to do it in a way it joins both strings together, like this:

```
Haldolium - The Flag (Remix 2022)
Alter Vu - Alien Terms
Raz,Upgrade - Baileys
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 3.1 you can use e.g.

```
for-each-pair(
  //p[@class='buk-horz-release-artists'], 
  //p[contains(@class,'buk-horz-release-title')]/a,
  function($p, $a) {
    $p/a => string-join(', ') || ' - ' || $a
  }
) => string-join(codepoints-to-string(10))
```

I don't know which XPath version your scraper supports but string-join requires at least XPath 2.

[XPath 3.1 online fiddle with the sample XPath and input](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=for-each-pair%28%0A%20%20%2F%2Fp%5B%40class%3D%27buk-horz-release-artists%27%5D%2C%20%0A%20%20%2F%2Fp%5Bcontains%28%40class%2C%27buk-horz-release-title%27%29%5D%2C%0A%20%20function%28%24a1%2C%20%24a2%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%24a1%2Fa%20%3D%3E%20string-join%28%27%2C%20%27%29%20%7C%7C%20%27%20-%20%27%20%7C%7C%20%24a2%2Fa%20%3D%3E%20string-join%28%27%2C%20%27%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%29%20%3D%3E%20string-join%28codepoints-to-string%2810%29%29&input=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-meta-parent%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-meta%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22buk-horz-release-title%20playlist-add-track%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Frelease%2Fthe-flag-remix-2022%2F3927104%22%3EThe%20Flag%20%28Remix%202022%29%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22buk-horz-release-artists%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fartist%2Fhaldolium%2F10646%22%20data-artist%3D%2210646%22%3EHaldolium%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22buk-horz-release-labels%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Flabel%2Fblue-tunes-records%2F5188%22%20data-label%3D%225188%22%3EBlue%20Tunes%20Records%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22buk-horz-release-released%22%3E2022-12-07%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-actions-parent%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-actions%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-play-queue%20playlist-add-track%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22playable-play%22%20data-type%3D%22release%22%20data-id%3D%223927104%22%20data-track%3D%2217096831%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20class%3D%22play-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%2Fstatic%2F4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg%23icon-play%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22playable-queue%20tooltip-secondary%22%20data-type%3D%22release%22%20data-id%3D%223927104%22%20data-track%3D%2217096831%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2016%2011%22%20class%3D%22queue-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%2Fstatic%2F4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg%23icon-add-queue%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22tooltiptext%22%3EAdd%20to%20queue%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22playable-playlist-add%20button-playlist-add%20button-icon%20space-right%20tooltip-secondary%22%20data-modifier%3D%22release%22%20data-type%3D%22release%22%20data-id%3D%223927104%22%20data-track%3D%2217096831%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20class%3D%22playlist-add-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%2Fstatic%2F4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg%23icon-plus%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22tooltiptext%22%3EAdd%20to%20playlist%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22buy-button%20horz-release-buy-button%22%20data-release%3D%223927104%22%20data-price%3D%22%241.29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22add-to-default%22%3E%241.29%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22launch-menu%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22launch-menu-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20class%3D%22icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%2Fstatic%2F4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg%23icon-chevron-down%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22loading-menu-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22icon%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20class%3D%22icon%20icon-ellipsis%20horz-release-ellipsis%20mobile-action%22%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-meta-parent%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-meta%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22buk-horz-release-title%20playlist-add-track%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Frelease%2Fbaileys%2F3931782%22%3EBaileys%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22buk-horz-release-artists%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fartist%2Fraz%2F105353%22%20data-artist%3D%22105353%22%3ERaz%3C%2Fa%3E%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fartist%2Fupgrade%2F252764%22%20data-artist%3D%22252764%22%3EUpgrade%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22buk-horz-release-labels%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Flabel%2Fregroup-records%2F33268%22%20data-label%3D%2233268%22%3ERegroup%20Records%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22buk-horz-release-released%22%3E2022-12-07%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-actions-parent%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-actions%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22horz-release-play-queue%20playlist-add-track%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22playable-play%22%20data-type%3D%22release%22%20data-id%3D%223931782%22%20data-track%3D%2217110875%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20class%3D%22play-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%2Fstatic%2F4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg%23icon-play%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22playable-queue%20tooltip-secondary%22%20data-type%3D%22release%22%20data-id%3D%223931782%22%20data-track%3D%2217110875%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2016%2011%22%20class%3D%22queue-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%2Fstatic%2F4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg%23icon-add-queue%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22tooltiptext%22%3EAdd%20to%20queue%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22playable-playlist-add%20button-playlist-add%20button-icon%20space-right%20tooltip-secondary%22%20data-modifier%3D%22release%22%20data-type%3D%22release%22%20data-id%3D%223931782%22%20data-track%3D%2217110875%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20class%3D%22playlist-add-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%2Fstatic%2F4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg%23icon-plus%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22tooltiptext%22%3EAdd%20to%20playlist%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22buy-button%20horz-release-buy-button%22%20data-release%3D%223931782%22%20data-price%3D%22%241.29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22add-to-default%22%3E%241.29%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22launch-menu%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22launch-menu-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20class%3D%22icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%2Fstatic%2F4fef40cebd6b915bcbe9695d5d543a01.svg%23icon-chevron-down%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22loading-menu-icon%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22icon%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20class%3D%22icon%20icon-ellipsis%20horz-release-ellipsis%20mobile-action%22%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E&input-type=HTML).

Comment: Hey @Martin Honnen, thank you, it worked! By the way, I've forgotten to say I was using xidel development build (XPath Command Line tool) which supports XPath up to 3.1.

Comment: @11ph22il, good choice of a tool with support for a modern version of XPath. If your problem is solved you can formally show that by accepting the answer clicking the check mark.